# Convert datetime string with milliseconds to datetime

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string (containing a datetime with milliseconds) into a DateTime type with milliseconds, but it isn't working for me.

```
Dim dt as String = "2018-02-02 08:01:16.111"
dim dtDate as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt)

RichTextBox1.AppendText(dtDate.ToString)
```

The result is always:  2/2/2018 8:01:16 AM

How can I have that DateTime object contain milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

**How can I have that DateTime object contain milliseconds?**

It already does have the milliseconds.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt As String = "2018-02-02 08:01:16.111"
    Dim dtDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt)
    Console.WriteLine(dtDate.Millisecond)
End Sub
```

> 111

What I guess you want to do is have it display the milliseconds when it is displayed as a string again. So String >> DateTime >> String. You do `RichTextBox1.AppendText(dtDate.ToString)` but ToString by default doesn't include the milliseconds.

Use the [ToString(string format) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a format string. Pass this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`

```
Dim dt as String = "2018-02-02 08:01:16.111"
Dim dtDate as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt)
RichTextBox1.AppendText(dtDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify datetime format in ToString method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Milliseconds part is "fff".

Comment: I don't want a string, I want a DateTime object.  I already have it in string format with the .fff

Comment: @Andrew he is saying that when you have your DateTime object, it contains the miliseconds but when you display it again, you do not specify to display miliseconds.